# Unit testing in Angular: Mocking RxJS observable with Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular12

I am unit testing an Angular 12 component.  The component fetches, on initialisation, an observable returned from a service (see `thing.service.ts` below).  It is assigned to a Subject, which is displayed in the html template (see `app.component.html` below) via the `async` pipe.

**AppComponent.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  public errorObjectSubject = null;
  public thingsSubject: Subject<Array<IThing>> = new Subject();

  constructor(private readonly _service: ThingService) {
    this._getAllProducts();
  }

  private async _getAllProducts(): Promise<void> {
    this._service.getAllObservableAsync()
      .pipe(take(1),
        catchError(err => {
          this.errorObjectSubject = err;
          return throwError(err);
        })
      ).subscribe(result => { this.thingsSubject.next(result) });
  }
}
```

The template subscribes to `public thingsSubject: Subject<Array<IThing>> = new Subject();` with the `async` pipe:

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
  <app-thing *ngFor="let thing of thingsSubject | async" [thing]="thing"></app-thing>
</div>
```

**thing.service.ts**

```
  constructor(private readonly _http: HttpClient) { }

  public getAllObservableAsync(): Observable<Array<IThing>> {
    return this._http.get<Array<IThing>>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos'); }
```

Here is the test setup.

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent,
    fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>,
    dependencies: { thingService: ThingServiceStub };

  function getThings(): Array<DebugElement> {
    return fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(ThingComponentStub));
  }

  beforeEach(async () => {
    dependencies = {
      thingService: new ThingServiceStub()
    };
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent, ThingComponentStub],
      providers: [
        { provide: ThingService, useValue: dependencies.thingService }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    //fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  describe('on initialisation', () => {
    let getThingsSubject: Subject<Array<IThing>>;

    beforeEach(() => {
      getThingsSubject = new Subject();
      (dependencies.thingService
        .getAllObservableAsync as jasmine.Spy).and.returnValue(
        getThingsSubject.asObservable()
      );
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should fetch all of the things', () => {
      //fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(
        dependencies.thingService.getAllObservableAsync
      ).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
    });

    describe('when the things have been fetched', () => {
      beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
        getThingsSubject.next()
        // getThingsSubject.next([
        //   {
        //     userId: 1,
        //     id: 1,
        //     title: 'string',
        //     completed: 'string'
        //   }
        // ]);
        //getThingsSubject.pipe().subscribe()

        tick();

        fixture.detectChanges();
      }));

      it('should display the things', () => {
        expect(getThings()[0].componentInstance.product).toEqual({
          name: 'product',
          number: '1'
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

**thing.service.stub.ts**

```
export class ProductServiceStub {
    public getAllObservableAsync: jasmine.Spy = jasmine.createSpy('getAllObservableAsync');
  }
```

I am trying to test how it works after the template has been populated with things (`IThing[]`).  I have a *passing* spec which calls the mock observable:

```
it('should fetch all of the things', () => {
  expect(
    dependencies.thingService.getAllObservableAsync
  ).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
});
```

However I hit the 'Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefine' when I attempt to test the template: `describe('when the things have been fetched'`.

I am not quite sure what is the problem.  Is it how I have setup the subscription to the Subject?  Or the change detection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the order in which you're calling things can be an issue.

Try this:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent,
    fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>,
    dependencies: { thingService: ThingServiceStub };
  

  function getThings(): Array<DebugElement> {
    return fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(ThingComponentStub));
  }

  beforeEach(async () => {
    dependencies = {
      thingService: new ThingServiceStub()
    };
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent, ThingComponentStub],
      providers: [
        { provide: ThingService, useValue: dependencies.thingService }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    // !! This (.createComponent) is when the constructor is called, so mock the observable
    // before here and change the subject to a BehaviorSubject.
    // Maybe subject will work as well.
    let getThingsSubject = new BehaviorSubject([{ name: 'product', number: '1' }]);
    (dependencies.thingService.getAllObservableAsync as jasmine.Spy).and.returnValue(
       getThingsSubject.asObservable()
    );
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  describe('on initialisation', () => {
    let getThingsSubject: Subject<Array<IThing>>;

    it('should fetch all of the things', () => {
      expect(
        dependencies.thingService.getAllObservableAsync
      ).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
    });

    describe('when the things have been fetched', () => {
      // maybe tick and fakeAsync are not needed but `fixture.detectChanges` is
      beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {

        tick();

        fixture.detectChanges();
      }));

      it('should display the things', () => {
        // !! Add this log for debugging
        console.log(fixture.nativeElement);
        expect(getThings()[0].componentInstance.product).toEqual({
          name: 'product',
          number: '1'
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm getting 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentInstance' of undefined' on `it('should display the products'` spec.  Trying with and with out `fakeAsync` / `Tick()`.  Any ideas?

Comment: I added a console.log for the 2nd test and it should help you debug. I am thinking `ThingComponentStub`s are not painted in the view. Maybe an `*ngIf` is blocking them.

Comment: Thank you very much.  The `console.log` helped me out a lot (I didn't know it was possible to log in the unit tests).  It was silly mistake on my part.  I had closed the inner `describe` before the outer 'describe'.  In other words, I removed `});` which was immediately before `describe('when the things have been fetched', () => {`.  Many thanks for your help. :)